# on windows 7/8, how to read usb device descriptor from a usb camera, and read picture stream with webcam meanwhile

Tags: camera, usb, webcam, libusb, winusb

1. I use webcam-capture(java api) to get video stream from a usb camera, it work fine.
2. I want read a usb device descriptor(store some private information), i find out that should install WinUSB or libusbk as a driver to the usb devices. and it test ok, read the descriptor success (by libusb_control_transfer api)

---

1. the question is:
2. befor I install WinUSB, the usb camera is a camera device in the windows device management list. the LibUSB work fail, can't open the usb devices, the error number is -5, means entrypoin not find
3. after I install WinUSB, libUSB api work ok, but the webcam program can't open the usb devices, it is a universal usb device in the windows device management list.

is there some way the webcam work ok, at the same time, i can read the usb device descriptor use libusb or use other something?

i tested on windows 7 and windows 8, have the same problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not possible because each of your applications needs a different driver. The only way this can work is if you use libusb and build you own capturing api on top which is quite complicated. As long as webcam-capture can not read the data you want to know about the webcam I am afraid this is not possible.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! do you know how to read the usb device descriptor use a very low api? for example, only depend on the hardware bus program. because I got a tool named "bus hound", it can read any descriptor from usb devices without specially driver